# Docker - NGINX - PHP-FPM - WordPress - The Page Isn’t Redirecting Properly

Tags: php, wordpress, docker, nginx, http-status-code-301

I had two WordPress websites on a Synology NAS at home running on NGINX with PHP-FPM 7.4 with virtual hosts.

I am moving these websites on a Debian VM also at home, and run the services in rootless Docker:

- MariaDB official Docker container
- NGINX official Docker container
- PHP-FPM official Docker container

These websites are exposed through a Traefik Docker container and my DNS and Let's Encrypt certificates are managed with the Cloudflare API.

When I try to access to [www.wordpress1.com](http://www.wordpress1.com), I get "The Page Isn’t Redirecting Properly" error.

I tried to add a phpinfo.php files in my WordPress websites, and I can access these files from WAN without any problem.
I tried to add a static website, and I can access it without any problem from WAN.

I have checked the logs for the two websites, and I get a lot of these errors:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1" 301 5
```

Here are my configuration files.

NGINX compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: always
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - backend
      - traefik
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - ./conf/servers.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./log:/var/log/nginx
      - nginx_data:/var/www/html
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.rule=Host(`static.com`,`www.wordpress1.com`,`www.wordpress2.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.nginx-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx.middlewares=nginx-https-redirect"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-secure.rule=Host(`static.com`,`www.wordpress1.com`,`www.wordpress2.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-secure.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.nginx-secure.service=nginx"
      - "traefik.http.services.nginx.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
      - "traefik.docker.network=traefik"

volumes:
  nginx_data:
    external: true

networks:
  backend:
    external: true
  traefik:
    external: true
```

NGINX servers.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name static.com;
    root /var/www/html/static;
    index index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/static_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/static_access.log;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.wordpress1.com;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress1;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/wordpress1_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress1_access.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.wordpress2.com;
    root /var/www/html/wordpress2;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/wordpress2_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/wordpress2_access.log;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

PHP compose.yaml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: custom/php:7.4-fpm
    container_name: php
    restart: always
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - backend
    user: 1234:1234
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
      - nginx_data:/var/www/html

volumes:
  nginx_data:
    external: true

networks:
  backend:
    external: true
```

PHP Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && install-php-extensions mysqli exif imagick zip
```

In the nginx_data volume, my permissions are 1234:1234, which are my docker user UID and GID on my rootless Docker install.

My database is on a mariadb docker container and the connection works (modified in the wp-config.php).

I don't understand why I can access the static website, why the phpinfo in the WordPress websites works, and why the WordPress websites doesn't work.
I though it was a problem of permission, but I used the "user" parameter in my PHP Docker container to specify it.

Thanks for your help.

[Edit] It seems the second WordPress website is displayed. So only the first one has this redirection error problem.
I tried with PHP v7.4 and PHP v8.1, same result.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you'll probably get better answers on https://serverfault.com/

Comment: The `www.wordpress1.com` domain is not given the redirect errors any longer. Also please consider to limit the code and configuration to the minimal needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: "www.wordpress1.com" isn't the real domain name, it is an example.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to delete the previous SSL if you copied it, also delete the .httacess file if you copied it from the old one, if the problem persists you should check if any php extension is not installed.

Comment: I did not use the previous SSL, they are generated by Traefik through Cloudflare.
I have renamed the .htaccess, because they are not used by NGINX, it is for Apache httpd.
I will check the PHP extension. I know some are already installed in the PHP Docker container, but maybe some are missing. I will keep you in touch.

Comment: Same problem with all the highly recommended WordPress php extensions installed.